# Add latency to a pulseaudio sink

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

How would one go about adding a fixed amount of latency, for example 15 milliseconds, to a sink in pulseaudio. This is possible using pavucontrol, however, I am unable to use such a tool in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

The latency is an attribute of the sink.

You can change it through anything that uses the Pulseaudio libraries.

If you cannot use `pavucontrol`, you could use `pacmd` with `set-port-latency-offset`.

If you cannot use that, either, please edit the question and explain what you can and cannot use in your situation.